# PyQT4 - QTextEdit

Tags: python, gui, pyqt4

Сап, Код.

Начал осваивать гуй на питоне (3 версия), вроде освоился с кнопкой. Но как только понадобилось что-то большее - сразу запор.

И так, имеется объект `QTextEdit` (или виджет, как правильно?) с названием "cmd". Хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопки строка из текстэдита попала в переменную (а можно и переменную вывести в текстэдит). Как мне это сделать?
Имеющийся код:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui.ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, app, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.app = app
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.connb("START", "text")

    def connb(self, what, to):
        what = getattr(self.ui, what)
        to = getattr(self, to)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(what, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), to)

    def text(self):
        with open("text.txt", 'w') as file:
            file.write("fp")
```

Comment: Получение текста из QTextEdit - toPlainText()

Answer (score 2):

```
self.ui.textEdit.append(i)
```